# Spring Boot @EnableScheduling conditionally

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to make @EnableScheduling conditional based on an application property? also is it possible to disable controllers based on properties too?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the same spring boot application used to serve web requests (but not run scheduled tasks on the same machine), and also install the same app on backend servers to run only scheduled tasks.

My app looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyApp {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
   }

}
```

And a sample scheduled job looks like this

```
@Component
public class MyTask {

   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
   public void doSomeBackendJob() {
       /* job implementation here */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I Solved this, here is what I did for future reference:

- Removed @EnableScheduling annotation from my app
- Added a new configuration class and conditional to enable/disable scheduling based on an application property

-

```
 @Configuration
 public class Scheduler {

    @Conditional(SchedulerCondition.class)
    @Bean(name = TaskManagementConfigUtils.SCHEDULED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    public ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor scheduledAnnotationProcessor() {
        return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

And the conditional class

```
public class SchedulerCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("com.myapp.config.scheduler.enabled"));
    }

}
```

Also, to disable web server on the backend server, just add the following to the application.properties file:

```
spring.main.web_environment=false
```

Answer (score 8):

You can annotate a bean injection like this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "your.property", name = "yes", matchIfMissing = true)
public void doSomeBackendJob() {
       /* job implementation here */
}
```

Bonus: Since you want to run different things in different machines, i.e., you will deploy the same app with different configurations, you could use spring profiles, if that's the case you can annotate a class or method like this:

```
@Component
@Profile({ Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION, Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_TEST })
public class TheClass{...}
```

Comment: Found this to be a lot of extra work since I need to disable/enable all jobs at once, check my answer

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty` will have no effect on a `@Scheduled` method as, like all conditions, it only affects bean registration. See the javadoc for further details: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html?is-external=true

Comment: My bad and thanks for the correction, I just edited the answer :)

Comment: That still won't work. The job will never run as it's never going to be scheduled

Answer (score 7):

I ended up creating a separate @Configuration class for scheduling and used the @ConditionalOnProperty annotation to toggle scheduling

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "scheduling", name="enabled", havingValue="true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class SchedulerConfig {

}
```

in my application.yml file I then added

```
scheduling:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: This worked but how to achieve it on the method level...

Comment: @nitinsridar The `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation works on methods, too. [This guide is handy](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty), and of course [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) are useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think scheduler is not configuration.
2. No need to set `prefix` in `@ConditionalOnProperty`
3. No need to create scheduler over `@Bean` in configuration class.

My variant:

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "scheduler.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MyScheduler {

    @Scheduled(...)
    public void doWork() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @TimStack Don't complain about the post and then OK it in Review. You defeat the purpose for what you are complaining about.

Comment: @Rob I am not complaining. If I believe an answer may truly be a helpful answer I'd rather see it edited and OP taught than see the post be deleted.

Comment: @TimStack
Expanded. :)

Comment: This worked but how to achieve it on the method level...

Comment: @nitinsridar you can achieve it on the method level by first appending the default value `-` to the injected cron expression inside the `@Scheduled` annotation of the cron job method you wish to turn off. for example: `@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.mytask:-}")`. Now all you have to do is comment out the corresponding cron definition in your `application.properties` file and restart the application. You should see that the scheduled method with the injected cron expression from property  `cron.mytask` does no longer run.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@ConditionalOnProperty` you could also use spring profiles to conditionally turn scheduling on or off.

First you need to define the spring profile that will activate your scheduling component. You can define an active spring profile by adding the property `spring.profiles.active` to your `application.properties` file. In my example i'll name the profile `cron`.

```
spring.profiles.active=cron
```

Next we annotate the scheduling component with `@Profile("cron")`.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
@Profile("cron")
public class ScheduleService {

    @Scheduled(...)
    public void cronJob() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `@Profile` annotation guarantees that the `ScheduleService` class will only be active when the `cron` profile is set. If it is not set both the class and the `@EnableScheduling` annotation will be ignored by `spring`.

You can also combine the `cron` profile with another spring profile. For example: Lets say you only want the cron jobs to be active when the application is running in production mode. In this case you could define another spring profile (for instance `prod`) and use it as a second condition in the `@Profile` annotation. First you add the `prod` profile to the spring property.

```
spring.profiles.active=prod,cron
```

Next you change the condition in `@Profile` to:

```
@Profile("prod & cron")
```

Now the `ScheduleService` is only active when both the `prod` and `cron` profiles are active.
More information on how to define advanced `@Profile` conditions can be [found here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-java).