# Make bean only if @EnableScheduling is present

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-bean

I am working on scheduling library. I am using `@EnableScheduling` to enable and run schedulers in Spring boot. There are many beans/components that I need in my scheduler. But I want to create the beans only if `@EnableScheduling` is present in the application. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Create a conditional rule that checks if a `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is present (as that is what the `@EnableScheduling` ultimately  registers.

Comment: You can find the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182633/spring-boot-enablescheduling-conditionally

Use conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at what [`@EnableScheduling`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) does, you'll see that it imports the [`SchedulingConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfiguration.html) configuration. Within this configuration class, a single bean is defined, called [`ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html).

This means that if you use [conditionals](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-conditional) to check for the existence of the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean, you can define beans that are only created when `@EnableScheduling` is present.

For this purpose, we can use the [`@ConditionalOnBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html) annotation. For example:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class)
public CommandLineRunner appRunner() {
    return args -> logger.info("Scheduling is enabled!");
}
```